# laravel redirect not redirecting to route after axios post

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

Simple problem here.

I've got this piece of code which gets triggered via an axios POST request:

```
if(Auth::id() == 4) {
    Log::info('redirect occurs: ');
    return redirect()->to('register');
}
```

The log occurs, but no redirect follows. i tried some variations but still nothing. any idea? (ive also tried auth.register, and only '/')

edit: this doesnt work either :

```
return view('auth.register');
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that `Auth::id()` actually returns `4`? Try to check with `Log::info(Auth::id())`

Answer (score 4):

You are using Axios to make a request which means you are making an asynchronous HTTP request with JavaScript.

When doing this you cannot use Laravel's responses to redirect the user - instead this would need to be done client side.

One option would be to return a json response containing the page to redirect to, then in your JavaScript change the url to the new url.